# Observing from a jumping frame of reference

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, everyday-life, relative-motion

Today, I was doing some exercise and started with jumping (normal jumping). The exact situation was something like this:

I was standing in front of a window, at my eye level, behind it was my neighbor's house. While jumping up I was able to notice that the window was moving downwards (as I expected), but my Neighbor's house was moving up (relative to the window, at least, if it is an illusion) which was not what I expected because, they should be moving with same acceleration.

I can see that this has something to do with relative magnification and our field of view. I think that the fact that my eyes can see a wider area of my neighbor's as opposed to my window has some role. But, when I try to explain it mathematically, all versions seem fair and I cannot fix myself in a particular line of thought.

I am not asking for the mathematical explanation, but for a clearer view of how I should Proceed. What exactly is happening?

Comment: "*I am not asking for the mathematical explanation, but for a clearer view of how I should Proceed.*" How you should proceed with what?

Comment: proceed with the calculation-i.e. to prove that if I jump, in that frame, the velocity of the house is in the upward direction with respect to the window. I want to know what concept is involved, like solid angle or optics, etc.

Comment: Suggest you try drawing a diagram—a side view of you standing on the floor, close to the window, and the neighboring house, somewhat further away. Draw "sight lines'--straight lines from your eye though the top and bottom of the window: Whatever is between those sight lines is what you can see through the window when your feet are on the floor.  Now draw a second head, higher up, and a second pair of sight lines. Where does the house fit within the new sight lines as compared to the old?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you are two feet from a window frame that is at your eye level, and you jump two feet straight up.

Say that your neighbor's house is 1000 feet away.

When you jump, at the height of your jump that window frame which was at zero degrees is now 45 degrees downward. But the angle to your neighbor's house has probably not changed enough to notice.

Comment: Ok! I was messing up with solid angle and area of cross-section. Thanks a lot.